# How to make a better graph plot without node overlapping?

Tags: r

I try to create a diagram with have nodes with text.

In some nodes the text is large and there is overlapping.

```
library(DiagrammeR)
grViz("
digraph twopi  {

# node definitions with substituted label text
node [fontname = Helvetica]
a [label = 'Motivation: 5W1H', style=filled, color=CornflowerBlue]
b [label = 'Where', style=filled, color=LimeGreen]
c [label = 'What', style=filled, color=LimeGreen]
d [label = 'How', style=filled, color=LimeGreen]
b1 [label = 'Who', style=filled, color=LimeGreen]
c1 [label = 'When', style=filled, color=LimeGreen]
d1 [label = 'Why', style=filled, color=LimeGreen]
e [label = 'Many words here 1', style=filled, color=LightCoral, fontsize = 7]
f [label = 'Many words here 2 and sth more', style=filled, color=LightCoral, fontsize = 7]
g [label = 'Many words here 3', style=filled, color=LightCoral, fontsize = 7]
h [label = 'Many words here 1s but add more here', style=filled, color=LightCoral, fontsize = 7]
k [label = 'Many words', style=filled, color=LightCoral, fontsize = 7]
l [label = 'Many words', style=filled, color=LightCoral, fontsize = 7]
e1 [label = 'Many words here 1 and', style=filled, color=LightCoral, fontsize = 7]
f1 [label = 'Many words here 1 plus big', style=filled, color=LightCoral, fontsize = 7]
g1 [label = 'Many words here 1', style=filled, color=LightCoral, fontsize = 7]
h1 [label = 'Additional word', style=filled, color=LightCoral, fontsize = 7]
q [label = 'More information here', style=filled, color=LightCoral, fontsize = 7]
r [label = 'Additional information he', style=filled, color=LightCoral, fontsize = 7]
k1 [label = 'Word only', style=filled, color=LightCoral, fontsize = 7]
q1 [label = 'Add text here', style=filled, color=LightCoral, fontsize = 7]
r1 [label = 'Need more space for this', style=filled, color=LightCoral, fontsize = 7]
s1 [label = 'Many words here 1', style=filled, color=LightCoral, fontsize = 7]
t1 [label = 'Many words here 1 and again', style=filled, color=LightCoral, fontsize = 7]
u1 [label = 'Text problem here', style=filled, color=LightCoral, fontsize = 7]
v1 [label = 'Go to the other', style=filled, color=LightCoral, fontsize = 7]
v2 [label = 'Against all text', style=filled, color=LightCoral, fontsize = 7]

graph [layout = neato]

node [shape = circle,
      style = filled,
      color = grey,
      label = '']

node [fillcolor = CornflowerBlue]
a

node [fillcolor = LimeGreen]
b c d b1 c1 d1

node [fillcolor = LightCoral]

edge [color = grey]
a -> {b c d b1 c1 d1}
b -> {e f g h}
c -> {k l}
d -> {q r}
b1 -> {e1 f1 g1 h1}
c1 -> {k1}
d1 -> {q1 r1 s1 t1 u1 v1 v2}
}")
```

However my problem is that when I insert the text in every node nodes are overlapped due to the length of text

How can I make the graph prettier/understandable without overlapping?

Comment: A hack is to insert newlines, e.g., `'Many words\n here 1\n and again'`.

Comment: Also, try `edge [color = grey, len = 1.5]`.